# Free MCBoot on 70000 series PS2 - White screen (of death?)

Tags: emulation, ps2, opl

I have a 70000 series slim PS2 in which the laser seems to have died, so I picked up a memory card with Free MCBoot v1.952 installed. I got the system to boot into Free MCBoot and everything looks great and OPL starts up fine.

I've had a very hard time finding any information with regards to how to get my games into the system, but here's what I've tried. Most of my work is done in Fedora 25, so I'm operating most of this from Linux. I set up a USB stick (yes, I know the caveats, but it's a slim system) as FAT32, and created the following directories:

- `CD`
- `CFG`
- `CHT`
- `DVD`

After accessing the stick through the PS2 and Free MCBoot, I also see these directories:

- `ART`
- `THM`
- `VMC`

Using a very simple PS2 game I have, Namco Museum, I ripped an `.iso` file using K9Copy. Everything seems fine - I can mount the `.iso`, it looks like the original, etc. I copied this `.iso` to the DVD folder and named it `slus_202.73.NamcoMuseum.iso`. I also checked the config file inside the .iso and I see this same `slus_202.73` identifier listed.

When I take this back to Free MCBoot, OPL sees the game and I am able to go to game settings (but didn't change anything) and select the game to run. The screen then turns white and nothing else happens. I don't get any colors flashing, etc. - just white.

From what I've found, this should just start up, but I can't seem to find any additional troubleshooting tips anywhere. Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found an ISO online to test whether my ISO generation was faulty.  When I tested it, I had the same problem - USB drive flashes, screen turns white, and then nothing further.  Any ideas how to test or troubleshoot?

Comment: Just a bump in hopes that someone out there has an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very important point: make sure you are using OPL version 0.9+.

That said, your main problem is that you cannot simply install the game for use with OPL by extracting it and naming the folder accordingly. In fact, it shouldn't even be in a folder, but at the root of your USB device. In order to load games off of a USB device with OPL, you have to use a particular Windows program (linked below) to automatically split the ISO into sectors to make it appear to the PS2 as though it is reading the data from a DVD, or the loading will fail. OPL is only there to provide a way to read what is on the USB device and to recognize when a game is there; the game is still processed as it would be when read from a DVD.

Which brings me to my second point: once you have properly installed the ISO using a given program (linked below), you have to use a defragmentation program (namely Power Defragmenter (linked below)) to make sure the game is completely contiguous, because if there is any fragmentation inside the game on the USB device, the game will freeze up and possibly cut out the same way it would with a scratched DVD.

As a side note, I know you can also load games from a network using OPL, but I haven't the slightest clue how to do that, as I've never done it myself.

A second note: when installing games, make sure you do it one at a time (install a game to a USB device, scan the device for fragmentation, defragment the game if needed, then install another game), because if more than one game is heavily fragmented, there won't be a large enough amount of contiguous free space to move parts of the game to when defragmenting it.

Unfortunately, no matter what, you will likely have to use Windows, and at the very least, you will have to use Wine, because as far as I know, there are no programs for installing PS2 games to USB devices on Linux, or macOS for that matter.

[USB Util v2 can be found here](https://archive.org/details/USBUtilV2.0FullEnglish_201607). Use it to install your ISOs to your USB device (FAT32).

[Power Defragmenter 3.0 can be found here](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/Power-Defragmenter.shtml); use the command line version if possible; the GUI has some issues if I remember correctly.

First format your USB disk as FAT32, then run USB Util v2, select your ISO, wait for it to install, and use Power Defragmenter 3.0 to scan your USB disk and repair any fragmentation. Make sure you have OPL 0.9.3 installed, and launch your game. It should run fine now. Good luck!

BTW, this is what the game should look like once it has been installed. There are two in the picture: *Metal Slug Anthology* and *Gran Turismo 4*. The format for a game's name is `ul.SERIALNUMBER.gameid.PART`and you should also have a file called `ul.cfg`.

[image: Picture of PS2 games installed on a USB device.]

Comment: Thanks for the great info!  Regarding the ripped/named files, that was exactly what another source said to do.  Clearly not such good information. I downloaded both Windows EXE files and I'm running USBUtil through Wine now.  I'll post back once I've had a chance to try it out.

Comment: @KirkDCO glad I could help, be aware that (at least on macOS) running USBUtil in Wine will cause it to think the amount of free space on your USB drive is the same as the amount of free space on your first HDD. Obviously not a huge problem unless you have paritcularly little free space, just something to keep in mind. Also have recently test the GUI for PowerDefragmenter_3.0 works fine after all, but make sure you choose to defrag files, *not* the whole disk.

Comment: Bummer.  Same problem.  I used USBUtil to copy the content to the USB stick and things look more or less like what you showed in the picture.  I started up FreeMCBoot and went to OPL (which is version 0.9.3).  I can see the game listed and when I select it the screen fades, the usb stick flashes, the screen turns white, and then....nothing.  Same problem as before.

Comment: @KirkDCO did you make sure to defragment all the game's file using slots 1-4 in PowerDefragmenter? If so you might try using another flash drive if you have one to spare, some USB 2.0/3.0 disks don't work properly (for example both my USB 1.0 and one of my USB 2.0 disks work fine, but the other 2.0 disk and my USB 1.1 disk dont). Also make sure the partition table on the USB disk is MBR not GPT.

Comment: @Allison E.E yes, I did the defragment step, but I have not tried another flash drive.  I'll give that a try and report back once I've had a chance to try it.

Comment: @KirkDCO another step which might seem trivial but could make a difference is to make sure the disk is plugged in to USB port 1 (left most). For some reason Sony has a tendency to make this the port that can actually load data (for example it was also the only one that could be used to mod COD 4 on the PS3, and is also the one you have to use for firmware updates on either console.).

Comment: Partial success!  I got a new USB drive that is specifically 2.0/3.0 compatible, and it is working now.  I was able to rip a PS2 game, but I haven't gotten a PS1 game working yet.  Is that out of scope?

Comment: @KirkDCO While almost any PS2 game should boot using OPL either locally or over a network, it does not have the ability to launch PS1 games. On top of that the structure of a PS1 game is different and will not work with USB Util. I do not know of any USB or network loaders for PS1 games, and have only found one disc based loader for backup PS1 games, which requires a proper PS1 disc, a modified save file for said official PS1 game, and does not work even still in my experience. Most modern computers are more than capable of emulating PS1 games very easily, so I would recommend just playing the

Comment: *continued* ISO from your backup directly that way. Also keep in mind that the PS3 has near perfect backward compatibility with PS1 games. If the PS1 emulation on a computer interests you, you will need a BIOS dump from your own PS1, if you don't own a PS1 you could dump your PS2 BIOS and use that to emulate your PS1 games in a PS2 emulator instead (let me know if you want info on how to do this).

Comment: Thanks for the details.   You have needed incredibly helpful.  I truly appreciate all your guidance!

Comment: @KirkDCO I'm happy to help whenever possible :)